# Magento 2 : dynamically update product option price

Tags: magento2, php

I would like to be able to dynamically set a product option price to 0 (marketing offer).

Based on admin configuration.

But I can't find which function I need to override.

Comment: At which time you want to update the option price, at the time of add to cart, at the time of update swatches etc???

Comment: explain in details

Comment: hello, yes sorry I would like to update it everywhere (on the product page, on the cart, checkout etc...) I would like the option to be free based on the option SKU, I will write the logic when I know the function to override. Thanks